# Plot for two discrete metric variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to create a graphic in which you can see the correlation between two variables that are discrete numeric.
These are `age` and `educ` from `carData::GSSvocab`.
`educ` only has the values from 0 to 20 and age is measured in year.
I don't have a good idea to plot this because if I use `geom_point` then there are many overlapping points.
I tried the following but I am not really satisfied with it:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(carData::GSSvocab,
       aes(x = age,
           y = educ)) + 
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: What's the question exactly? Ideas for a better way to visualize this data? That's on the verge of opinion-based questions, which are discouraged on SO. It's much better if you have an idea of what you want to do and then come back to get help making that specific task happen. For finding ideas of types of viz that might work, I like the [Data Viz Project](https://datavizproject.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the dataset you're using, I have the feeling that the variable `educ` is more a class variable than a true numerical variable. 
Personally, I will rather used `educ` as a factor instead of trying to plot it as numeric and I will add a boxplot to obtain something like that.

So, it should look like:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(educ), y = age)) +
  geom_jitter(width = .2, size = .5, color = adjustcolor("black",alpha=.6)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_flip()
```

And the following graph:

[image]

And I think it makes a little bit more sense that there is a correlation between `educ` and `age` with older people having a lower score of `educ` and younger people having a  higher score of `educ`.

Does it make sense to you ? (Again, it's my personal understanding of this dataset)

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought about this, too, but I am not quite sure if I like it. I will overthink this.

Comment: Sure ! You're welcome if it helps you to think differently to these data

Answer (score 1):

your scatterplot produces numerous ties in the bivariate distribution and obscures a large number of points in the display and it clearly is not that useful. To overcome this problem, group age into a factor with multiple levels and produce a boxplot instead of a scatterplot.

```
Cnt2Fac <- function(x, breaks = NULL) {
 if(is.null(breaks)) breaks <- unique(quantile(x, 0:10/10))
 x <- cut(x, breaks, include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)
 levels(x) <- paste(round(breaks[-length(breaks)]), ifelse(diff(breaks) > 1,
 c(paste("-", breaks[-c(1, length(breaks))] - 1, sep = ""), "+"), ""),
 sep = "")
 return(x)
}

plot(educ ~ Cnt2Fac(age,c(18,36,54,72, 90)), 
data = carData::GSSvocab[complete.cases(carData::GSSvocab[,c("educ","age")]),], 
xlab='Age', ylab='Education', main='Education vs Age')
```

[image]

Comment: There might have been reasons why they wanted to keep this in ggplot, so switching to base plots might not be helpful

Comment: @camille You are right but I like the idea anyway and it's no problem for me to do the same in ggplot. Thank you Shirin!

Comment: @TobiSonne my pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

My preference for such situations is to try to depict something about the density of points:

```
library(carData)
library(ggplot2)
data('GSSvocab')

p <- ggplot(GSSvocab,
            aes(x = age,
                y = educ))

p + geom_hex() # or...
p + geom_bin2d() # or...
p + geom_point(alpha = 0.05) + geom_density_2d()
```

My worry with converting years of education to a `factor` (as suggested in another answer) is (1) this does not reflect how you would actually analyze the data in a correlation test; (2) depicting the box plots might make you visually over-confident in the central tendency of categories for which there aren't a lot of data (e.g. years 0:5)--the real take-home is that there just aren't many data points there; and (3) it sets up an arbitrary choice: why make years of education into the `factor`, why not make age the `factor`?

Comment: I agree, maybe making `age` as a factor could make more sense than `educ` but manipulating data in both way could also a good manner to have a sense of the dataset and what they are representing. In my anser, I was proposing more a way to escape the scatterplot and an another way to visualize these data by using a factor and a boxplot.